# Merging case classes if the values are None

Tags: scala

I have a case class that has properties that are optional:

```
case class ProductAttributes(price: Option[Int], localtionId: Option[Int], colorCount: Option[Int])
```

I also have a case class that has default values that every user should have set:

```
val defaultProduct= ProductAttributes(locationId = Some(1), colorCount = Some(1))
```

Now I want to apply the `defaultProduct` values to any `ProductAttributes` instance, and if the instance has a `None` for any of the values in `defaultProduct`, I want the value to be set with the value from `defaultProduct`.

Is there a neat way of doing this in pure Scala? (no external libs)

Comment: Pattern matching?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez yes but there are so many combinations of if a property is None or not...

Comment: could you please explain with example?

Comment: `ProductAttributes(prod.price orElse default.price, prod.locationId orElse default.locationId, ...)` (you can extract `a.x orElse b.x` to a function)? There are ways of doing it with less boilerplate but they require additional libraries.

Answer (score 3):

Well, as pointed out elsewhere, you can simply use `Option`'s `orElse` method:

```scala
val default: ProductAttributes = ???

def applyDefaults(pa: ProductAttributes): ProductAttributes =
  ProductAttributes(
    price = pa.price.orElse(default.price),
    locationId = pa.locationId.orElse(default.locationId),
    colorCount = pa.colorCount.orElse(default.colorCount)
  )
```

But the question is: is this really a useful function? Because once you've called it, you probably want to somehow make use of the fact that all the values are now defined. But how? You can call `.get` on those `Option`s, but then your program will crash if you ever forget calling `applyDefaults`. Or you can use "safe" methods like `getOrElse(xxx)`, but then what are you going to put there instead of `xxx`? Whatever you put there, it's dead code because, well, you've applied the defaults.

The problem here is that the function signature doesn't express what the function does: it makes the optionality go away. One way to rectify that is to add a type parameter to `ProductAttributes` that tells you if the values are optional or not:

```
case class ProductAttributes[F[_]](
  price: F[Int],
  localtionId: F[Int],
  colorCount: F[Int])

type Id[A] = A
val default = ProductAttributes[Id](20, 17, 3)

def applyDefaults(pa: ProductAttributes[Option]): ProductAttributes[Id] =
  ProductAttributes[Id](
    price = pa.price.getOrElse(default.price),
    locationId = pa.locationId.getOrElse(default.locationId),
    colorCount = pa.colorCount.getOrElse(default.colorCount)
  )
```

The signature now tells the reader what the function does: it takes a `ProductAttributes` with optional fields and returns one with non-optional fields. Then you can perform whatever logic is necessary later on without risking crashes (because of `.get`) or writing dead code.